# How do I draw a spinner with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I first tried implementing it through two triangles. And got a satisfactory output

```css
#wrapper {
  margin-left: 40vw;
  margin-top: 20vh;
}

#fidgetu {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3vh;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
}

#fidgetd {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3vh;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid red;
  animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="fidgetu">
  </div>
  <div id="fidgetd">
  </div>
</div>
```

I guess drawing a fidget spinner would require 4 `div` circles and 3 `div` rectangles to connect the central circle to the other three and a wrapper `div` (applying animate property to this div). But the positioning is messing up.

Now how do I position them appropriately such that the entire block rotates around its center?

Comment: animate the wrapper https://codepen.io/wildbeard/pen/JNQzEZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set an element as the base spinner, and then 3 childs of this one as the outer circles.

if the outer ones are positioned over the first one, just rotating the base elements will handle the rotation of the others.

A litlle tricky are the curves connecting the inner and the outer. I have set a solution, but there is some missalignment. It still needs a last adjustment on the pixel values (but it's hard to get it exactly)

```css
.spinner, .outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.spinner {
  background-color: teal;
  border: solid 20px tomato;
  margin: 100px;
  animation: rotate 4s infinite linear;
}

.outer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: solid 20px blue;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
}

.outer:before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   transform: translate(-91px, 104px);
   box-shadow: 0px -55px 0px -33px blue;
}

.outer:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   transform: translate(-83px, -156px);
   box-shadow: 0px 55px 0px -33px blue;
}


.outer:nth-child(1) {
   transform: translate3D(120px, 0px, -10px);
}

.outer:nth-child(2) {
   transform: rotate(120deg) translate3D(120px, 0px, -10px);
}

.outer:nth-child(3) {
   transform: rotate(240deg) translate3D(120px, 0px, -10px);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner">
    <div class="outer"></div>
    <div class="outer"></div>
    <div class="outer"></div>
</div>
```